request early appointment for asylee - United States
Have a few questions:

If say a person applies for asylum and the wait period for getting the first appointment with USCIS where they decide whether to push you to the court system takes too much time, can you request to expedite this?
Secondly, what happens when the person self deports before this?
Lastly, what happens when the person self deports after this but before the docket reaches the judge and a court date gets set?


The whole point of seeking asylum is that you want to stay here because you are afraid of going back to your home country. So then why does it matter if it "takes too much time"? During that time, you get to stay here, which is what you want.

Perhaps acceleration might be useful for an asylum applicant who wishes to travel internationally; doing so is unlikely to be possible for one waiting for processing.]

@DavidRecallsMonica: An asylum applicant who has a need to travel abroad and return to resume their asylum application can try to apply for Advance Parole.

@user102008 Certainly true, though success (as you note with "try to apply") is not certain.


If say a person applies for asylum and the wait period for getting the first appointment with USCIS where they decide whether to push you to the court system takes too much time, can you request to expedite this?

You can, but you have to have a really really good reason. Not having the patience to wait for the process to work out is not a good reason. See the guidance on the USCIS page on this topic.

Secondly, what happens when the person self deports before this?

The pending application terminates.

Lastly, what happens when the person self deports after this but before the docket reaches the judge and a court date gets set?

Once the removal proceedings start, the person starts accumulating days of unlawful presence. If the person accumulates too many days of unlawful presence they become inadmissible for periods of time (depending on how many unlawful presence days accrued). See here for more details on inadmissibility and unlawful presence.
Note that while the asylum application is pending the applicant doesn't accrue unlawful presence days, but once the application is rejected or withdrawn - this is no longer the case.

What I meant by "self deports after this" is, after the first appointment with USCIS (where say it enters the court system) but before the master hearing?

@StingRay what are you trying to achieve?

@litteadv I am just trying to know my options.
